# 403 error (Forbidden) after login with OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I tried to login with `filterChain` method: when I log in with login and password, I successfully enter, but with using Gmail and GitHub accounts error 403 displayed. At first login I see authentication window with basic information, but when I apply it, error 403 always displays.
I can't use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and disable csrf!
For implementing I used article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login: it's the newest update, but still it has few critical errors.

My project on GitHub: https://github.com/sedub01/CafeBarApplication, I haven't push new changes yet (if you'd noticed some files missed, I'll add them).
First appearence of OAuth2 implementing you can see in `13d9361ab8682a1f3ad32e2acd95218d0f18a949` commit.

File `SecurityConfig.java` (when I comment `authorizationEndpoint`, displays 403 error, otherwise 404 error; also I don't know how to implement `accessTokenResponseClient`, because returned class doesn't exist)

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity //for global security use (and @PreAuthorize too)
public class SecurityConfig {
    //...

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/design", "/orders").hasAuthority(Role.USER)
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN)
                    //resources below are available without registration
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll())
            .formLogin(login -> login //login conf. stage
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    //redirected path after login (if second param is true, redirection will be forced)
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/design", true))
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/loginFailure")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/design", true)
                    .authorizationEndpoint(endpoint -> endpoint
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize-client")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(authorizationRequestRepository())
                        )
                        .redirectionEndpoint(endpoint -> endpoint
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/redirect"))
                        // .tokenEndpoint(endpoint -> endpoint
                        // .accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient()))
                    )
            .logout(logout -> logout
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
        return http.build();
        //Used https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest>
    authorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    // @Bean
    // public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> 
    // accessTokenResponseClient() {
    
    //     return new NimbusAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
    // }
```

File `login.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:insert="~{blocks/common :: common}">
    <title>Cafe Bar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div th:insert="~{blocks/navbar :: navbar}"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div th:insert="~{blocks/jsconnect :: jsconnect}"></div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <span th:if="${param.error != null}" class="validationError">
            Unable to login. Check your username and password.
        </span>
        <p>
            New here? Click <a th:href="@{/register}">here</a> to register.
        </p>
        <form method="POST" th:action="@{/login}" id="loginForm">
            <label for="username">Username: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" /><br />
            <a th:href="@{/oauth2/authorization/google}">Sign in with GMail</a>
        </form>
        <h3>Login with:</h3>
        <p th:each="url : ${oauth2_urls}">
            <a th:text="${url.key}" th:href="${url.value}">Client</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
#properties for OAuth2
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: <google client-id>
            client-secret: <google client-secret>
          github:
            clientId: <github clientId>
            clientSecret: <gitgub clientSecret>
```

And also, can you give me a hint, how to make it so that at the first login there is authorization, and then authentication at each next login? Besides login and password, I want user to contain address, phone number, etc.